# what is ...{} (three dots followed by curly brackets) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand Javascript/React and in my understanding ... would be the spread, however, in this example, the usage doesn't make sense to me:

```
render() {
        const { showLoading, hideLoading } = this

        const value = {
            ...this.state,
            showLoading,
            hideLoading
        }

        return (
            <LoadingContext.Provider value={value}>
                <LoadingContext.Consumer>
                    {
                        ({ showLoading, hideLoading, loading, message }) => (
                            <Fragment>

                                <Users  {...{ showLoading, hideLoading }} />

                                <Departments {...{ showLoading, hideLoading }} />

                                <Loading {...{ loading, message }} />

                            </Fragment>
                        )
                    }
                </LoadingContext.Consumer>
            </LoadingContext.Provider>
        )
    }
```

Users, Departments and Loading only receives two arguments each, so why are these ...{}?

Comment: it makes no sense. please ask the vendor of the code.

Comment: Is it spreading an inline-created object literal?  That's strange.  Seems like an obtuse way to just pass those two values.

Comment: This actually does make sense; `<Users showLoading={showLoading} hideLoading={hideLoading} />` would be more verbose.

Comment: @David React syntax would otherwise be `<Users showLoading={showLoading} hideLoading={hideLoading} />` so I suppose spread attribute syntax makes this much shorter

Comment: Could be further simplified to `{(loadingState) => (<><Users {...loadingState} /><Departments {...loadingState} /><Loading {...loadingState} /></>)}` though :)